# Maven repository for spark-jobserver 0.7.0

Tags: java, maven, github, spark-jobserver

I'm setting up a maven java project to implement SparkJobs in a spark-jobserver. In the [GitHub Spark JobServer page](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) they mention the new 0.7.0 version, but on the maven repository that they provide I can't find it.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spark-jobserver</id>
        <name>spark-jobserver</name>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/spark-jobserver/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The newest one is 0.6.2 , Are they just announcing this version? or where I can find it, since I'm starting with this I would like to start with the newest one.

Comment: The 0.7.0 is a SNAPSHOT version, not released yet, then, you should stay on the latest stable version, 0.6.2, as you pointed out earlier

Comment: @DamCx thank you for your quick answer. Then I just need to wait. :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. I will switch my comment as an answer, can you validate it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0.7.0 is a SNAPSHOT version, not released yet, then, you should stay on the latest stable version, 0.6.2, as you pointed out earlier